# Kmodes which.min(dist) : replacement has length zero error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

This is the head of my data set:

```
     SUB_SEGMENTO    GENERO ESTADO_CIVIL INSTRUCCIÓN
3          Masivo MASCULINO      SOLTERO   BACHILLER
5          Masivo MASCULINO      SOLTERO      BASICA
6          Masivo  FEMENINO       CASADO    PRIMARIA
7          Masivo MASCULINO      SOLTERO   BACHILLER
11 Nuevos prepago  FEMENINO       CASADO      BASICA
12         Masivo MASCULINO      SOLTERO     NINGUNA
                 PROFESION CIUDAD.CANTON  año
3                  POLICIA        CALVAS 1980
5                 EMPLEADO SANTO DOMINGO 1989
6     QUEHACER. DOMESTICOS     MARCABELI 1981
7  BACH.CIENCIAS GENERALES     LATACUNGA 1996
11                EMPLEADO        AMBATO 1980
12               JORNALERO    PEDERNALES 1991
```

All of the features are factors. I am running a cluster function:

```
clusters <- kmodes(muestra3, 3, iter.max = 25, weighted = FALSE)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error in cluster[j] <- which.min(dist) : replacement has length zero

Comment: Can you provide your data in a better format - e.g. `dput(head(muestra3))` ? And can you please specify what package `kmodes()` comes from?

Comment: It is from library klaR.

Comment: I cannot paste here the output of the code dput(head(muestra3)) because it is too long, but I can show you each variable level number: SUB_SEGMENTO:27  GENERO:3  ESTADO_CIVIL:6   INSTRUCCIÓN     PROFESION:279 CIUDAD.CANTON:190  año:71